# What does "$*" at the end of a shell command mean

Tags: linux, shell

In a sample shell script, the command was -

```
. <sourced_file.sh> $*
```

What does the `$*` mean?
Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`$*` expands to all of the arguments that were given to the script in which it appears, or to the current shell function if it appears inside a function.

It's usually incorrect usage though, because it breaks arguments that contain spaces into multiple arguments. More correct is `"$@"` which preserves the original arguments even if they have spaces in them.

Answer (score 1):

`$*` is a variable holding all positional parameters starting from 1 (the arguments to the current shell script)

[man 1 bash](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash):

> The shell treats several parameters specially. These parameters may
>   only be referenced; assignment to them is not allowed.
>
> ### *
>
> Expands to the positional parameters, starting from one. When the
>   expansion occurs within double quotes, it expands to a single word
>   with the value of each parameter separated by the first character of
>   the IFS special variable. That is, "$*" is equivalent to "$1c$2c...",
>   where c is the first character of the value of the IFS variable. If
>   IFS is unset, the parameters are separated by spaces. If IFS is null,
>   the parameters are joined without intervening separators.
>
> ### @
>
> Expands to the positional parameters, starting from one. When the
>   expansion occurs within double quotes, each parameter expands to a
>   separate word. That is, "$@" is equivalent to "$1" "$2" ... If the
>   double-quoted expansion occurs within a word, the expansion of the
>   first parameter is joined with the beginning part of the original
>   word, and the expansion of the last parameter is joined with the last
>   part of the original word. When there are no positional parameters,
>   "$@" and $@ expand to nothing (i.e., they are removed).

Usually you want to use `"$@"` though:

> "$*" is equivalent to "$1 $2 ..." whereas
>   "$@" is equivalent to "$1" "$2" ...

Answer (score 1):

`$*` is the alias for all the arguments given to the current script.

For example, if you launch :

```
./test_script.sh arg1 arg2 arg3
```

If you do `echo $*` in test_script.sh you will display : `arg1 arg2 arg3`

Answer (score 1):

Google on `bash $*` gives you **immediately** [the advanced bash scripting guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/) which gives you the answer. You often should prefer `"$@"`

Answer (score 0):

$* are the arguments

So if you script "foo.sh" is

```
#!/bin/sh
gethostip $*
```

And you call foo.sh -d localhost

it will be the same as

```
gethostip -d localhost
```

Minbd though, $* will not play nice with arguments having spaces.

Answer (score 0):

It’s “all the arguments”:

```
$ cat >test<<EOF
> echo \$*
> EOF
$ bash test foo bar
foo bar
```